# php imagejpeg(): Unable to open '/pic/upload/123.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ftp

I was looking since few days how to solve that problem and tried all i found here. I am not very good at php, so i hope someone here finde the problem faster than me :)

Permissions are on 777
The picture get uploaded to /pic/tmp ... and i also tried to change to upload into /pic thats all no problem....
... only if i want to do something with imagejpeg()

thanks for help!

(some tries are already there remarkt with // .... but not all i tries)

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "adress";
$ftp_user_name = "user";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";

$destination_file = "/pic/upload/tmp/". basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploaddir="/pic/upload/tmp/";
$newpath="/pic/upload/";
$ftppath="ftp://".$ftp_user_name.":".$ftp_user_pass."@".$ftp_server;
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

$alterPfad=$ftppath.$uploaddir."123.jpg";
$neuerPfad=$newpath."123.jpg";
//$neuerPfad=$ftppath.$newpath."123.jpg";
//$neuerPfad=".".$newpath."123.jpg";

$bildEigenschaft = getimagesize($alterPfad); 
$widthOld = $bildEigenschaft[0]; 
$heightOld = $bildEigenschaft[1]; 
$image_filetype = $bildEigenschaft[2]; 

$width=$widthOld;
$height=$heightOld;
    if($width>670)
        {list($width,$height)=Groessenberechnung($width,$height,670);
        }
    if($height>500)
        {echo "<p>berechnung 2.1 weite:".$width." hoehe:".$height."</p>";
        list($height,$width)=Groessenberechnung($height,$width,500);
        }

$image_old = imagecreatefromjpeg($alterPfad); 
$image_new = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 

imagecopyresampled($image_new, $image_old, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $widthOld, $heightOld); 

//tp_rename($conn_id,$destination_file,$uploaddir."123.jpg");   //ftp_put($conn_id,"/pic/upload/123.jpg","/pic/upload/tmp/123.jpg", FTP_BINARY); 
//ftp_raw($conn_id,imagejpeg($image_new,$neuerPfad)); 
    imagejpeg($image_new,$neuerPfad);
...
...
...
?>
```

Comment: use `$neuerPfad=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$newpath."123.jpg";`

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer :) ...
 $neuerPfad=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$newpath."123.jpg";  
 in combination with 
ftp_raw($conn_id,imagejpeg($image_new,$neuerPfad));

Answer (score 0):

I would `echo` the value of `$neuerPfad` to see which path it is trying to open.